# Exception handling for CompletatbleFuture<Void> when used with Spring's Async

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future, spring-async

I am quite new to this completable future concept. I am using Spring's async annotation and for this I have added a file configuration for executor and exception handler as follows:

```
@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(CORE_POOL_SIZE);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(MAX_POOL_SIZE);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(QUEUE_CAPACITY);
    taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncThread - ");
    taskExecutor.initialize();
    return taskExecutor;
}

@Override
public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    return asyncExceptionHandler;
}
```

And then I have a method which I want to run asynchronously and return CompletableFuture :

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Void someMethod() {
     try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
}
```

Now if some exception happens in the above method call, then how should I handle the exception here?

Note: If I don't return CompletableFuture and return void instead, it will go to the exception handler AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler, but as per my requirement I want to return CompletableFuture Void.

Comment: The way your async method is written does not make a lot of sense to me - are you sure you don't want the actual processing be done in the completable future itself, ie as a `submit()`ted `Runnable`?

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior. take a look at `AsyncExecutionAspectSupport` class method `handleError`:

```
protected void handleError(Throwable ex, Method method, Object... params) throws Exception {
    if (Future.class.isAssignableFrom(method.getReturnType())) {
        ReflectionUtils.rethrowException(ex);
    }
    else {
        // Could not transmit the exception to the caller with default executor
        try {
            this.exceptionHandler.obtain().handleUncaughtException(ex, method, params);
        }
        catch (Throwable ex2) {
            logger.warn("Exception handler for async method '" + method.toGenericString() +
                    "' threw unexpected exception itself", ex2);
        }
    }
}
```

**If the method return type be a variant of `Future`** then always `if (Future.class.isAssignableFrom(method.getReturnType()))`  evaluates to `true` and the exception is re-thrown to be handled by the higher level caller, so it is not handled by `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler`.

You can handle the exception by the facilities provided to you by `CompletableFuture` such as `handle(BiFunction<? super T, Throwable, ? extends U> fn)` method or use try/catch block.